# Power BI - If then and divide by total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need the correct syntax for a measure within PI Bower if possible please.

I am trying to say:

```
IF(TYR[Status] = 'Active', Sum(Contact_URN))
```

Thanks

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax and requesting to learn syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the measure you are looking for, based on your example would be:

```
Your Measure = Calculate(Sum(Contact_URN); Filter(TYR; TYR[Status] = "Active"))
```

If conditions in measures are filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an IF, that has this syntax:

```
IF(logical_test>,<value_if_true>, value_if_false)
```

like:

```
IF(TYR[Status] = 'Active';Sum(Contact_URN);BLANK()) 
// remove the BLANK() for the else condition if it is not what you want
```

or with a SWITCH(), that has this syntax:

```
SWITCH(<expression>, <value>, <result>)
```

```
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    TYR[Status] = 'Active'; SUM(Contact_URN)
    // insert other conditions here if needed   
)
```

If this doesn't work, please provide more details about your fields and tables.